# leiningen clj-time dependencies in Eclipse getting namespace not found exception

Tags: eclipse, maven, clojure, dependencies, leiningen

I'm using leiningen in Eclipse. I can't seem to load the clj-time libraries.

Here's my project.clj:

```
(defproject MatchAnal "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
:description "FIXME: write description"
:url "http://example.com/FIXME"
:license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
        :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
:keep-non-project-classes true
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"] [clj-time "0.5.1"]])
```

I clicked on Leiningen -> Update Dependencies in my project and I can see the clj-time-0.5.1.jar in the Leiningen dependencies tree.

When I try to use clj-time from the repl or in a namespace I get a namespace not found excpetion. For example if I type this in the repl: 
    (use 'clj-time.core)
I get:
Exception namespace 'clj-time.core' not found  clojure.core/load-lib (core.clj:5380)

Comment: Try to remove keep-non-project-classes and then  try lein clean and then lein deps and see whether it is going to work

Comment: Weird project name by the way!

Comment: That worked. Thanks! I forgot I'm not supposed to use capital letters in the project names. Is there any way to change the name? I guess it should be match-anal?

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments, I'm posting the answer here:

Try to remove :keep-non-project-classes and then try lein clean and then lein deps and see whether it is going to work.